# Django Q object not chaining correctly

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-q

I'm querying a ManyToMany field (tags). The values come from a list:

```
tag_q = Q()

tag_list = ["work", "friends"]
for tag in tag_list:
    tag_q &= Q(tags__tag=tag)

Post.objects.filter(tag_q)
```

When I have only one value, it works flawlessly, but when more objects are stacked it always return an empty queryset.

I didn't used tags__tag__in=tag_list because it returned any post that contained any of the tags in the tag list (an OR filter), and I need an AND filter here.

This is my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=19, choices=TagChoices.choices())

class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts', blank=True)
```

This is the Q object that is being passed in the filter query:

```
(AND: ('tags__tag', 'work'), ('tags__tag', 'friends')
```

Comment: You can not work with a `Q` object like that: a filter is an *existential* quantifier, not a universal. It means you are looking for a *single* `Tag` that has as `tag` name `work` and `friends` at the *same* time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not work with a `Q` object like that: a filter is an *existential* quantifier, not a universal. It means you are looking for a *single* `Tag` that has as `tag` name `work` and `friends` at the *same* time.

What you can do is work with a list of tags, and then count if the number of `Tag`s is the same as the number of items to search for, like:

```
tag_list = ['work', 'friends']

Post.objects.filter(tags__tag__in=tag_list).annotate(
    ntags=Count('tags')
).filter(ntags=len(set(tag_list))
```

since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) instead of [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
tag_list = ['work', 'friends']

Post.objects.filter(tags__tag__in=tag_list).alias(
    ntags=Count('tags')
).filter(ntags=len(set(tag_list))
```